# AttributeError at type object 'Services' has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, python-class

I newly started to develop Django. I want to connect my python algorithm and Django web ui so I tried to connect both of them in views.py but I encountered a problem.

It says **AttributeError at type object 'Services' has no attribute 'app'** but I declared it in the **queryOnMetadataModel.****init**. I don't know what is wrong. Could someone help me?

These are my code snippets;

- **queryOnMetadataModel.py**

```
from Neo4jConnection import App   
import json

class Services:
    def __init__(self):
        uri = "neo4j+s://a50f760a.databases.neo4j.io:7687"
        user = "neo4j"
        password = "password"
        self.app = App(uri, user, password)
    
    def find_node_type(self,nodeName):
        node_type = self.app.find_node_type(nodeName)
        self.app.close()
        return node_type
```

- **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from BitirmeTeziSourceCode.queryOnMetadataModel import Services

import sys
sys.path.append(".")

# Create your views here.

def home(request):

    data = Services.find_node_type(Services , 'Region')
    
    nodes = {
        "nodes" : data
    }
    
    return render(request , "index.html" , nodes)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("" , views.home)
]
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQXnm.png)

I want to access output of **Services.find_node_type(Services , 'Region')** from **index.html**

Answer (score 1):

You need to make instance first instead of directly using class so:

```py
def home(request):
    instance=Services()
    data = instance.find_node_type('Region')
    
    nodes = {
        "nodes" : data
    }
    
    return render(request , "index.html" , nodes)
```

> **Note:** Also it is better to write classes in singular case so it is better to write `Service` not <s>`Services`</s>.